# How to change theme configs in Prime React

Tags: reactjs, primereact

I am using Diamond template of Prime React. Before 9.6.0 version of Prime React we could change theme configs with PrimeReact. Like

```
PrimeReact.changeTheme(layoutConfig.colorScheme, datacolorScheme, 'theme-link', () => {
                    setLayoutConfig((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, datacolorScheme }));
                });
```

But its deprecated. It says use PrimeReactContext instead. I digged Primereact page, their github changelog etc to how to use with PrimeReactContext. But I couldn't find anything. It just written below code in their page. Which is not quite clear for all layout configs. I mean what would be callback for example. What should I put there instead of `setlayoutConfig` ?

```
import { PrimeReactContext } from 'primereact/api';

//Use in a component
const { changeTheme } = useContext(PrimeReactContext);

changeTheme(currentTheme: string, newTheme: string, linkElementId: string, callback: Function)
```

My current version is 9.6.2

I want to know how to use below methods with PrimeReact Context

```
PrimeReact.changeTheme(layoutConfig.colorScheme, datacolorScheme, 'theme-link', () => {
                    setLayoutConfig((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, datacolorScheme }));
                });

                PrimeReact.changeTheme(layoutConfig.theme, datatheme, 'theme-link', () => {
                    setLayoutConfig((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, datatheme }));
                });

                PrimeReact.ripple = data.ripple === 'true';
                setLayoutConfig((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, ripple: data.ripple === 'true' }));

                setLayoutConfig((prevState) => ({
                    ...prevState,
                    scale: layoutConfig.scale
                }));
                document.documentElement.style.fontSize = layoutConfig.scale + 'px';
                if (isSlim() || isHorizontal() || isCompact()) {
                    setLayoutState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, resetMenu: true }));
                }
```